# Asset type "episode" using Youtube Content ID API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm making one application that allows my users upload their videos on the youtube channel. This channels are from one partner account and are configured to be television channels, so, they have "Shows". One video belongs one show, a show can have a lot of videos.
So, in the creation of all the information package I create an asset. According the youtube content ID API documentation

> The asset's type: This value determines the metadata fields that you
>   can set for the asset. In addition, certain API functions may only be
>   supported for specific types of assets. For example, composition
>   assets may have more complex ownership data than other types of
>   assets.
>
> Valid values for this property are: composition, episode, general, movie,
>   music_video, season, show, sound_recording, video_game web

This type, "**episode**" allows to set in the METADATA objet the video's ID SHOW (and other info, of curse)

```
$metadata = new Google_Metadata();
$metadata->setShowCustomId($VIDEO_OBJET['showid']);
$metadata->setSeasonNumber($VIDEO_OBJET['seasson']);
$metadata->setEpisodeNumber($VIDEO_OBJET['ep_number']);
```

When I create the asset

```
$asset = new Google_Asset();
$asset->setType("episode");
```

I receive this message:

```
400 Bad Request

- Show headers -


{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtubePartner.assets.insert",
    "reason": "showsAndMoviesNotYetSupported",
    "message": "Shows and movies assets are not yet supported."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Shows and movies assets are not yet supported."
 }
}
```

If I create the asset with another type, different to the "episode" type, for example: "web", I can't assign the ID show, ¿or not? O.o"

So, this is my question: How can I create an "episode" type asset? or How can I set the ID Show  using the Youtube Content ID API?

Please, help. My soul will be greateful by the etternity XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggests, that asset type is not **yet** supported, so there's not much you can do at this time. It's been brought up with the engineering team, though, and hopefully will make it into the API at some point in the future.